# How to run gatsby on a PORT mentioned in a .env file

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to run gatsby on a different port, But the port had to come via .env file.

I tried to put env varibale in commandline

```
gatsby develop -p process.env.GATSBY_PORT
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
. ./.env && gatsby develop -p $GATSBY_PORT
```

This will export the variables from the .env file .

Comment: Of course "./.env" should point to where ever your .env file is located.

Comment: It gives /bin/sh: ../../.env: Permission denied
error Command failed with exit code 126.

Comment: Make sure the user has read access to the .env file. The simplest approach would be something like `chmod +r ../../.env`, but keep in mind your specific security context as that command will grant all system users 'read' access.

Comment: Have you tested this? Beacuse it still doesn't work for me,